# javascript structure, is my game loop executing?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm developing a HTML5 3D isometric game (think sim city 2000 style graphics) and I'm not so sure which parts of my code are, and aren't executing.

The game was originally created by modifying a tutorial I followed and I've been trying to restructure it to make it easier to work with. However, I can't work out if the main function is being executed or there's some other reason why I'm just getting a blank canvas.

I have an older version of the code running but I still can't work out what's gone wrong since I restructured and simplified it.

This is what's going on in my code...

first off the webpage starts the game.js script and runs the init function:

```
<body onload='init()'>
    <div id="content">
        <h2>Tile Engine</h2>
        <script src="js/game.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
```

The init function looks like so:

```
var init = function() {
    initCanvas();
    initTiles();
    initMap();
    handleKeyboard();
    handleMouse();

    main();

    // Let's play this game!
    then = Date.now();
    setInterval(main, 1); // Execute as fast as possible
};
```

The main function is below:

```
var main = function() { 
    now = Date.now();
    delta = now - then;

    update(delta / 1000);
    render();

    then = now;
};// Main game loop
```

If you would like to see the full code base the git repository can be found below (I've made it public):
https://bitbucket.org/suipaste/isotile/overview

One of my main issues is that I'm not sure how I should approach debugging js so I can't really tell if the main function is running.

Comment: You should setup a JSFiddle instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`console.log()` is your friend.

Here's how you use it:

```
var main = function() {
    console.log('main called');
    .
    .
    .
};
```

When you run your code in the browser, you will see a log in the console if your `main()` function is executed.

You can access the console by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> and then clicking on `Console`.

Comment: I would rather say that breakpoints (`debugger;`) are your friends.

Comment: @plalx In JavaScript? I know there are IDE's that allow you to use breakpoints, but I, for one, rarely utilize that functionality. `console.logs` are the easiest and most generic way to debug (especially when you don't have a fancy IDE).

Comment: Every decent modern browser has development tools allowing to place breakpoints. You do not need any external IDE for this.

Comment: @plalx Good point, you should answer this question with the `debugger;` method.

Comment: @jsve - Almost every modern browser including those on Android lets you use `debugger;`... It's the easiest way set a breakpoint.